# JVM will not start when starting Glassfish on RHEL

Tags: linux, glassfish, java

GlassFish 3.0.1
RHEL 6.3

When trying to start GlassFish I get the following JVM error:

```
JVM failed to start: com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherException: The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
Command start-domain failed.
```

I have plenty of free memory: 3689 MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had added a new http-listener which was on the same port as another http-listener.  I removed the new http-listener from the GlassFish config file domain.xml and rebooted the server and everything came back up.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, it's related to domains in glassfish.

- No domains defined : glassfish won't start
- Several domains : you need to set domain to use in startup script.

Comment: from the commmand line I am issuing the following as 'root' --- asadmin start-domain domain1   So I have one domain defined.